# Pivoting XML data in Pandas with tags as headers of pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7, pandas-groupby

I have converted an XML data to a pandas dataframe. Now I wish to pivot the data to reach my ideal df output. Please help me.

My current out:

```
       data                name
0      Aruba               Country or Area
1      Population, total   Item
2      1960                Year
3      54211               Value
4      Aruba               Country or Area
5      Population, total   Item
6      1961                Year
7      55438               Value
8      Aruba               Country or Area
9      Population, total   Item
10     1962                Year
11     56225               Value
12     Aruba               Country or Area
13     Population, total   Item
14     1963                Year
15     56695               Value
16     Aruba               Country or Area
17     Population, total   Item
18     1964                Year
19     57032               Value
```

I am pasting the last line directly of what I am using to pivot.

```
xml_df = xml_df.pivot(index='data', columns='name')
```

Desrired Output:

```
Country or Area   Year     Item                 Value
Aruba             1960     Population, total    54211
Aruba             1961     Population, total    55348
```

etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can try `groupby` on `name` and `cumcount` , followed by `unstack`:

```
df.assign(k=df.groupby('name').cumcount()).set_index(['k','name']).unstack()
```

---

```
                data                                
name Country or Area               Item  Value  Year
k                                                   
0              Aruba  Population, total  54211  1960
1              Aruba  Population, total  55438  1961
2              Aruba  Population, total  56225  1962
3              Aruba  Population, total  56695  1963
4              Aruba  Population, total  57032  1964
```

Details:
[`cumcount()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html)

```
df.groupby('name').cumcount()
```

This groups by name and `Numbers each item in each group from 0 to the length of that group - 1` and using [`df.assign()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) we assign a new column `k` to the dataframe. Then using `set_index()` wee set the name and `k` column as index so you get:

```
print(df.assign(k=df.groupby('name').cumcount()).set_index(['k','name']))
                                data
k name                              
0 Country or Area              Aruba
  Item             Population, total
  Year                          1960
  Value                        54211
1 Country or Area              Aruba
  Item             Population, total
  Year                          1961
  Value                        55438
2 Country or Area              Aruba
  Item             Population, total
  Year                          1962
  Value                        56225
.......
.....
```

Using this data we use [`unstack()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) which helps "*Pivot a level of the (necessarily hierarchical) index labels, returning a DataFrame having a new level of column labels whose inner-most level consists of the pivoted index labels*" hence this converts the last level (by default) of the index to columns as we require.

Comment: Can you please explain shortly how the cumcount and unstack works avoiding tech jargons ?

Comment: @KaustubhUrsekar sure, allow me some time, i will update the answer with explanation

Answer (score 1):

Another way with pivot:

```
df['idx'] = df.name.eq('Country or Area').cumsum()
df.pivot(index='idx', columns='name', values='data')
```

Output:

```
name Country or Area               Item  Value  Year
idx                                                 
1              Aruba  Population, total  54211  1960
2              Aruba  Population, total  55438  1961
3              Aruba  Population, total  56225  1962
4              Aruba  Population, total  56695  1963
5              Aruba  Population, total  57032  1964
```